# Is InputStream.available() supposed to block?

Tags: java, android, inputstream

The (Oracle's) javadoc of the `InputStream.available()` method says the following:

> Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream. The next invocation might be the same thread or another thread. A single read or skip of this many bytes will not block, but may read or skip fewer bytes...

So the thing is that from a conceptual point of view, I would say that it makes sense that this method does not block. Otherwise, the purpose of "not blocking" in the next call to `read()` does not make much sense, because we could potentially block in `available()` itself.

The thing is that at my company we recently found several Android bluetooth implementations that block on the `available()` method, and we don't know if that's a bug we should report to vendors or just that `available()` can block.

Comment: It shouldn't block, but whatever the case may be, there are few if any correct uses of `available().` Most probably you shouldn't be calling it at all.

Comment: @EJP well, the call to available() was part of some optimizations we wanted to implement, so it's not like it was mandatory, but it was desirable to count on the "expected" behavior I described above. But yeah, I guess it's difficult to answer this one given the unclarity of the Javadoc

Comment: We also have this with a Toughshileld T700. Not found yet a solution